# UI not updating with WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `Datagrid` in my view bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>`. The collection is populated from a method invoked in the viewmodel constructor using a Linq to EF method. which selects records from a view in my SQL Server db:

Property:

```
private ObservableCollection<vwAccountHeader> _accountHeaderCollection;
public ObservableCollection<vwAccountHeader> AccountHeaderCollection
{
    get { return _accountHeaderCollection; }
    set
    {
        _accountHeaderCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AccountHeaderCollection");
    }
}
```

Method:

```
private void GetAccountHeaders()
{
    var query = from a in _context.vwAccountHeaders
        select a;

    AccountHeaderCollection = new ObservableCollection<vwAccountHeader>(query);
}
```

Selected Item:

```
private vwAccountHeader _selectedAccountHeader;
public vwAccountHeader SelectedAccountHeader
{
    get { return _selectedAccountHeader; }
    set
    {
        _selectedAccountHeader = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAccountHeader");
    }
}
```

The collection populates as expected on initialisation. I then have the functionality for the user to select a row from the Datagrid and edit said row:

[image]

The selected item changes are persisted back to a sql table not the sql View bound to the DataGrid however this table is the parent of the view so changes are also persisted to the View. For example here is my `SaveEdits` command:

```
private void SaveAccountEditsCommandAction()
{
    var query = from a in _context.tbAccounts
                where SelectedAccount.accountId == a.accountId
                select a;

    foreach (var a in query)
    {
        a.Div1AccNo = SelectedAccount.Div1AccNo;
        a.AccountName = SelectedAccount.AccountName;
        a.CompanyName = SelectedAccount.CompanyName;
        a.ContactEmail = SelectedAccount.ContactEmail;
        a.ContactName = SelectedAccount.ContactName;
        a.SubscriptionLevel = SelectedAccount.SubscriptionLevel;
        a.Responsible = SelectedAccount.Responsible;
        a.notes = SelectedAccount.notes;
        a.IsActive = SelectedAccount.IsActive;
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

These changes are persisted to my `VWAccountHeaders` View in SQL Server. I am implementing `INotifyPropertyChnaged` and the Xaml binding is set to update on 'PropertyChanged':

```
<DataGrid x:Name="AccountsHeaderDataGrid" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding AccountHeaderCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccountHeader, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="350">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account No" Binding="{Binding Path=div1accno, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Company Name" Binding="{Binding Path=companyname, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Subscription Level" Binding="{Binding Path=subscriptionlevel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Region List" Binding="{Binding Path=region_list, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Active" Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid/>
```

Despite this I just can't get the UI to reflect changes in the underlying data without closing the app & re-running. I can see the `DataGrid` flickering on save so can see it's re-binding but it just doesn't pick up the changes in the underlying view. Do I need to refresh my data context somehow or am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys. I have solved this issue at last!

Here is my RefreshEntities() method which invokes `MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;` which essentially overwrites the context entity & reloads the collection with the new data from the DB. You're telling EF to overwrite the entity you pass in. I'm invoking this method wherever I'm persisting changes to that view:

```
    private void RefreshEntities()
    {
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext;
        var objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<vwAccountHeader>();
        objectSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
        AccountHeaderCollection = new ObservableCollection<vwAccountHeader>(objectSet);
    }
```

Seems very verbose but works great. I would recommend this for any MVVM WPF app where you are trying to update a view in the UI which has changed by user interaction with an associated table in the EF framework model. Essentially where there's a cross relationship between tables & a view & you need to update that view in the UI.

`MergeOption.OverwriteChanges` overwrites all pending changes but you can use `MergeOption.PreserveChanges` to merge reloaded values just to your edited values.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because the collection is not changing and so the event may not get triggered automatically. So in *SaveAccountEditsCommandAction* try raising property change for *AccountHeaderCollection*

Comment: No, you shouldn't raise property change on Collection because the Collection has not changed. It's the in-side item binding not working.

Comment: Correct, the ObservableCollection hasn't changed, it's the entities object not binding to the changes. But how to rectify this?..

Comment: @Hardgraf Is SelectedAccount a clone of the original one or is it referring to the same object in the collection?

Comment: No, Selected account is a vwAccountHeader object rather than a selected row from the the collection. I'm updating the tbAccounts table & the changes are persisted to the VWArticleHeaders view which is what you see bound to the DataGrid in the UI. I've checked the DB on SaveChanges() & everything is saved back to the db as I'd expect. Included selectedItem property in the question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your collection is created only once and it is not magically refreshing later.
Try calling GetAccountHeaders() in the end of SaveAccountEditsCommandAction().

Comment: Tried this, the collection is the same. It looks like the vwAccountHeader EF object hasn't picked up the changes from the db

Comment: So changes are stored in db but EF is not picking them  unless you restart your app? Have you tried selecting data from DB after clicking save. Are they already in DB. Also can you set breakpoint when you call GetAccountHeaders() in the end of SaveAccountEditsCommandAction(). Is downloaded data up to date then?

Comment: Exactly. The data in the db has been persisted on invoking GetAccountHeaders() but the linq query doesn't pick up the changes from _context.vwAccountHeaders...

Comment: Could you try calling context.refresh before creating new collection?

Comment: VS2013 here with EF 6. That method doesn't exists unfortunately. I've tried invoking Dispose() on the context & newing up a context but same result :(

Comment: So esentially SaveChanges() is working, the UI is bound correctly to the ViewModel, it's the EF context not returning changes from the DB that's causing the issue.

Comment: If I persist changes directly to the view (vwAccountHeaders) rather than tbAccounts then the OnservableCollection & UI update properly except of course I get an exception on SaveChanges() because the view has no UPDATE, INSERT etc. functionality...

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to solve you issue. I have no experience with EF6. Good luck.